# Empty index column when reading with read_clipboard

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, clipboard

Hy everybody: I'm trying to read data from a software: it generates a table like this:

```
Data1   |   Data2  | Data3
Data4   |   Data5  | Data6
Data7   |   Data8  | Data9
```

I can copy it to clipboard, and data values are separated with tabular signs, so I thouhgt it can be read to pandas.
If I do

```
ExportedData=pd.read_clipboard(names = ["ColA","ColB","ColC"], header=None)
```

or

```
ExportedData=pd.read_clipboard(names = ["ColA","ColB","ColC"], header=None, index_col=[0])
```

or even

```
ExportedData=pd.read_clipboard(names = ["ColA","ColB","ColC"], header=None, index_col=[])
```

I have the same result: a column index appears empty:

|  | index | ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| 1 |  | Data4 | Data5 | Data6 |
| 2 |  | Data7 | Data8 | Data9 |

BUT if I do

```
ExportedData=pd.read_clipboard(names = ["ColA","ColB","ColC"], header=None, index_col=False)
```

What I have is:

|  | index | ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | nan | Data1 | Data2 |
| 1 | 1 | nan | Data4 | Data5 |
| 2 | 2 | nan | Data7 | Data8 |

I would like to know how can I obtain an index column:

| index | ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| 1 | Data4 | Data5 | Data6 |
| 2 | Data7 | Data8 | Data9 |

Thanks in advance...

---

The data copied directly from the software is

```
102 0   0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1300.873   28.473  5.601   29.8726 -173.483    1466.4655   102-1   0
    102 0.0625  0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1303.46    28.473  5.601   29.8726 -173.8331   1465.4711   102-1   0.0625
    102 0.125   0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1306.048   28.473  5.601   29.8726 -174.1832   1464.4767   102-1   0.125
    102 0.1875  0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1308.636   28.473  5.601   29.8726 -173.7106   1463.4823   102-1   0.1875
    102 0.25    0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1311.224   28.473  5.601   29.8726 -172.7678   1462.4879   102-1   0.25
    102 0.3125  0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1313.812   28.473  5.601   29.8726 -171.825    1461.4936   102-1   0.3125
    102 0.375   0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1316.4 28.473  5.601   29.8726 -170.8821   1460.4992   102-1   0.375
    102 0.4375  0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1318.987   28.473  5.601   29.8726 -169.9393   1459.5048   102-1   0.4375
    102 0.5 0_ELU_00    Combination Max -1321.575   28.473  5.601   29.8726 -168.9964   1458.5104   102-1   0.5
    102 0   0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3601.347   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -642.3739   404.781 102-1   0
    102 0.0625  0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3603.935   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -640.5449   404.482 102-1   0.0625
    102 0.125   0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3606.522   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -638.7159   404.183 102-1   0.125
    102 0.1875  0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3609.11    -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -636.887    403.884 102-1   0.1875
    102 0.25    0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3611.698   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -635.058    403.585 102-1   0.25
    102 0.3125  0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3614.286   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -633.229    403.286 102-1   0.3125
    102 0.375   0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3616.874   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -631.4  402.9871    102-1   0.375
    102 0.4375  0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3619.461   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -629.571    402.6881    102-1   0.4375
    102 0.5 0_ELU_00    Combination Min -3622.049   -8.57   -74.276 9.0095  -627.7421   402.3891    102-1   0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately, if your copy/paste is correct, it looks like spaces are used both as field separator and within the data, which makes it impossible to parse unambiguously. Make sure that the separators are not tabulations, otherwise you'll have to try to export your data in a better format. What is the source software?

Comment: Source code are Tables from SAP2000, a software for structural calculations. Seems parsing is correct, as it generates a column for "Combination" and another one for "Max"/"Min".
In any case, I think I have achieved a solution, by fullfilling the column "index" that appears empty... I explain it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the separator with a regex:

```
ExportedData = pd.read_clipboard(names=["ColA","ColB","ColC"],
                                 header=None, sep=r'\s*\|\s*')
```

If really you have tabulations:

```
ExportedData = pd.read_clipboard(names=["ColA","ColB","ColC"],
                                 header=None, sep=r'\t')
```

Output:

```
    ColA   ColB   ColC
0  Data1  Data2  Data3
1  Data4  Data5  Data6
2  Data7  Data8  Data9
```

Comment: I have done both alternatives, but none of them work: I continue having an empty index column:
|     |  index | ColA   | ColB   |  ColC |
| ---| --------| ------- | ------- | ------ |
|  0 |           | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
|  1 |           | Data4 | Data5 | Data6 |

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77563119/edit) your question with the exact content of your software's output? Please put it in between triple backticks to preserve the formatting

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is generating a column for index (with no header) and an index column (empty).
What I have done to solve it is adding the last two lines of this code (the first one is the original one, that reads information from Clipboard):

```
DataRead=pd.read_clipboard(names = ["ColA","ColB", 'ColC'], engine='python', header=None)
DataRead['index']=np.arange(len(DataRead))
DataRead=DataRead.reset_index(drop=True)
```

With this, I have this

|  | index | ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| 1 | 1 | Data4 | Data5 | Data6 |
| 2 | 2 | Data7 | Data8 | Data9 |

It is not *exactly* what I was expecting, but in any case, seems to work... ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Thanks, @mozway, for your time.